# How do I buy a used bike?

Tags: product-rec, used-bike

Since we have a lot of questions asking about buying a used bike, I thought we could do a community wiki on how to buy used bikes as a be-all, end-all.

There are a few main questions:

1) [How do I check if a used bike is safe to ride ?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41043/8219)

2) [How do I assess the value of a used bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41041/8219)

Feel free to add others as answers, one question per answer.

Answer (score 1):

**How do I evaluate the value of a used bike?**

Well, the simple answer is a bike is worth as much as someone is willing to pay for it.

As guidelines, a few websites may be useful:

- [Craigslist](https://www.craigslist.org) (See what similar bikes are going for in your area)
- [EBay](http://www.ebay.com/) (Online retailer)
- [Bicycle Blue Book](http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/) (Gives values for certain bikes; can be useful as a rough guideline)
- [Bikepedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/) (Gives values for certain bikes when new, along with their original components)
- [Velobase](http://www.velobase.com/) (Database of vintage cycling and marketplace)

Comment: I'd like to stress that "worth what someone will pay for it" is not "what some optimistic seller has listed it for"   A bike listed at a silly starting price is not a reflection of its worth.

Answer (score 1):

### How do I make sure a bike fits?

Bike fit is critical.  If the rider and the bike don't fit together properly, you'll hurt more and sooner, and rides won't be enjoyable.   Get it right!

- [What to do on a test ride?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/a-test-ride-for-a-new-bicycle)
- [How to make sure the bike is the right size?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/how-do-i-make-sure-my-bikes-the-proper-size)
- [How to make sure the bike fits when I can't ride it?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/257/how-to-best-determine-if-a-bike-will-fit-without-riding-it) (buying online)
- [How to get the saddle/seat height right?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-position-for-my-bicycle-seat)
- [Should I buy a slightly too-big or too-small bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/11179/is-it-better-to-have-a-slightly-big-or-slightly-small-bike)

Answer (score 0):

**How do I see if a used bike is safe to ride?**

We've covered this in a variety of answers.

(Summary)

Links to useful answers:

- [Safety Checks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/22908/safety-check-for-a-used-bike)
- ...